# Display php output on a txt file Linux command line with output formating

Tags: php, linux, command-line-interface

I am trying to output in a text file, which I am able to do sucessfully but the output is all in one line.
This is what I am doing:

```
$myfile='data_'.date("y-m-d").'.log';
exec ('php Calculations.php', $output);
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../../../logs/'.$myfile, $output.PHP_EOL, LOCK_EX|FILE_APPEND);
```

in Calculations.php

```
declare(strict_types=1);
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$container = require 'config/container.php';
$calculations = $container->get(\App\Service\Calculate::class);
$calculations->handle();
```

In Calculate class

```
public function handle($verbose = true)
    {
...code....
 echo'PROCESSING STARTED'.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
...code....
echo'Values'.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
...code....
echo'PROCESSING ENDED'.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output of log file

```
PROCESSING STARTEDValuesPROCESSING ENDED
```

The output is not formatted.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Concatenating `PHP_EOL` should do the right thing. Are you reading the file on a different OS than the one where you created it?

Comment: On Linux, `PHP_EOL` is `\n`, but Windows expects lines to end with `\r\n`.

Comment: I am executing this in Ubuntu

Comment: Use `"\n"` instead of `PHP_EOL`, it seems like there's a problem with that constant.

Comment: What do you see if you look at a hex dump of the file?

Comment: I'm not sure why, what did the hex dump show before you changed it?